# Get Facebook extra details in MVC 4 using simple membership Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

Currently I used default

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient(appId: "", appSecret: "");
```

to authorize the Facebook user.

Also it will add UserName into UserProfile table. Now is there any way can I access and store some default details from user's Facebook account into the same table?

Let's say I need Email, Birthday, First Name , last Name.

What changes do I need to make into the default table UserProfile which created as part of Simple Membership. And what changes I need to make in Account Model and Account Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the link below:

[Using OAuth Providers with MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc)

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: @David Use below new link :                                       http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc